# Which wiki markup parser does Wikipedia use?

Tags: php, html-parsing, wikipedia, wiki-engine

None of [these](http://pear.php.net/search.php?q=text+wiki&in=packages) parsers are used by Wikipedia; None of them handle the wiki code correctly.

Does anyone know what parser Wikipedia uses?

Comment: Wikipedia is run by MediaWiki software, and I'm pretty sure the parser is built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia uses [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), which has [its own parser](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classParser.html).

Comment: I am looking for just the parser, not the whole engine.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia runs on the [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) engine, originally written precisely to use for Wikipedia.

They implement [their own parser](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/Parser_8php_source.html). A more thorough description of the parser is available in the [manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParser.php).

Comment: Do you know how to use [their own parser](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/Parser_8php_source.html) in a simple example?

Comment: @Peter: I've never worked with the MediaWiki source, but judging by the manual, you'll want to instantiate the class and call either the [parse](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classParser.html#a0e3f2edd4bd47376953dfad4dcfc9c74) method. If it's just parsing to HTML, you might be able to use the [internalParse](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classParser.html#a6b7ac0b498eb30e00dfcfb5722cfab9f) method instead.

Comment: The page die when I try to instantiate the class. Neither `$wiki =& new Parser();` or `$wiki = new Parser();` works.

Comment: @Peter: I expect the parser has some amount of dependencies which you may or may need to provide somehow (e.g. include other files). Again, I have never touched or used this code, so I can't say for sure; if nothing else, you should be able to figure it out by turning on error messages and dealing with any problems one at a time.

Comment: @Peter: You may also find the following blog post helpful to understand the parser better: http://musialek.org/?p=94